# Syntastics doesn't recognize own java packages

Tags: java, vim, ant, package, syntastic

Syntastic reports errors, that certain packages do not exist, although I defined them by myself in this project. How can I make Syntastic recognize those?

I use the ant build system, and already tried to add those .class files by myself via:

```
:SyntasticJavacEditClasspath
```

and then added in the new window the directory containing the .class files

```
~/.../mainProject/ant-bin/lang
```

It did not change anything.

Comment: Change `~` to a full path.

Comment: It works! Unfortunately Syntastics forgets about it everytime I start gvim new. Is there a way to make it remember those packages without changes in the .vimrc, but only project specific?